# Travis-CI tries to start rake starting while pom.xml is available in directory

Tags: travis-ci

I'm trying to build my Java project with Travis-CI.

The project which I'm trying to build is in a subdirectory in my repository. Because of this I've added a "cd" command to goto the directory and a "ls" command to verify that the correct directory opened.

What I see in the log that correct directory is opened and that the pom.xml is available. What i would suspect is that Maven is started. That is not the case. Rake is started. What I'am not seeing?

The .travis.yml file:

```
language: java
before_install: 
 - cd Back-end
 - ls
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
```

The log file:

```
$ bundle --version

Bundler version 1.5.3

Applying fix for NPM certificates
before_install.1

$ cd Back-end
before_install.2

$ ls

pom.xml Procfile src system.properties

$ rake

rake aborted!

No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'

/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

The command "rake" exited with 1.

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that travis-ci checks at the very start of the build if there is a `pom.xml` file, before even `before_install`. The good news is though that you can set you own script to run. Add `script: mvn test` to your `.travis.yml` file(Or whatever  other maven command you want use to run your tests).

Answer (score 0):

Might be that this is outdated now. It seems that Travis functionality has changed. If you choose "More Options > Trigger build" you will get to a CUSTOM build dialog. It will ignore your travis.yml file in the Git repository. To run a manual build one must copy content of `travis.yml` file and paste it in the dialog's "Custom config" field.